# if connection is keep alive how to read until end of stream php

Tags: php, http

```
$f = fsockopen("www....",80,$x,$y);

fwrite("GET request HTTP/1.1\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n");

while($s = fread($f,1024)){
    ...
}
```

The above stalls because of the `Connection: keep-alive`, and works with `Connection: close`.

How do you do it without stalling?

Comment: As an aside, you realize you have a quote error, right?

Comment: @Daedalus I can verify that the quote error is not the problem. I placed the bounty because I have a similar issue and have already wasted too much time trying to fix it :)

Comment: Good catch, @Daedalus, I didn't catch that. I'm with rdlowrey though, that kind of error would have been different.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It depends on the response, if the `transfer-encoding` of the response is `chunked`, then you read until you encounter the "last chunk" (`\r\n0\r\n`).

If the `content-encoding` is `gzip`, then you look at the `content-length` response header and read that much data and then inflate it.  If the `transfer-encoding` is also set to chunked, then you must dechunk the decoded response.

The easiest thing is to build a simple state machine to read the response from the socket while there is still data left for the response.

When reading chunked data, you should read the first chunk length (and any chunked extension) and then read as much data as the chunk size, and do so until the last chunk.

Put another way:

- Read the HTTP response headers (read small chunks of data until you encounter `\r\n\r\n`)
- Parse the response headers into an array
- If the `transfer-encoding` is chunked, read and dechunk the data piece by piece.
- If the `content-length` header is set, you can read that much data from the socket
- If the `content-encoding` is gzip, decompress the read data

Once you have performed the above steps, you should have read the entire response and you can now send another HTTP request on the same socket and repeat the process.

On the other hand, unless you have the absolute need for a keep-alive connection, just set `Connection: close` in the request and you can safely read `while (!feof($f))`.

I don't have any PHP code for reading and parsing HTTP responses at the moment (I just use cURL) but if you'd like to see actual code, let me know and I can work something up.  I could also refer you to some C# code I've made that does all of the above.

EDIT:  Here is working code that uses `fsockopen` to issue an HTTP request and demonstrate reading keep-alive connections with the possibility of chunked encoding and gzip compression.  Tested, but not tortured - use at your own risk!!!

```
<?php

/**
 * PHP HTTP request demo
 * Makes HTTP requests using PHP and fsockopen
 * Supports chunked transfer encoding, gzip compression, and keep-alive
 *
 * @author drew010 <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125463/if-connection-is-keep-alive-how-to-read-until-end-of-stream-php/11812536#11812536>
 * @date 2012-08-05
 * Public domain
 *
 */

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$host = 'www.kernel.org';

$sock = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$sock) {
    die("Connection failed.  $errno: $errstr\n");
}

request($sock, $host, 'GET', '/');

$headers = readResponseHeaders($sock, $resp, $msg);
$body    = readResponseBody($sock, $headers);

echo "Response status: $resp - $msg\n\n";

echo '<pre>' . var_export($headers, true) . '</pre>';
echo "\n\n";
echo $body;

// if the connection is keep-alive, you can make another request here
// as demonstrated below

request($sock, $host, 'GET', '/kernel.css');
$headers = readResponseHeaders($sock, $resp, $msg);
$body    = readResponseBody($sock, $headers);

echo "Response status: $resp - $msg\n\n";

echo '<pre>' . var_export($headers, true) . '</pre>';
echo "\n\n";
echo $body;


exit;

function request($sock, $host, $method = 'GET', $uri = '/', $params = null)
{
    $method = strtoupper($method);
    if ($method != 'GET' && $method != 'POST') $method = 'GET';

    $request = "$method $uri HTTP/1.1\r\n"
              ."Host: $host\r\n"
              ."Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
              ."Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"
              ."\r\n";

    fwrite($sock, $request);
}

function readResponseHeaders($sock, &$response_code, &$response_status)
{
    $headers = '';
    $read    = 0;

    while (true) {
        $headers .= fread($sock, 1);
        $read    += 1;

        if ($read >= 4 && $headers[$read - 1] == "\n" && substr($headers, -4) == "\r\n\r\n") {
            break;
        }
    }

    $headers = parseHeaders($headers, $resp, $msg);

    $response_code   = $resp;
    $response_status = $msg;

    return $headers;
}

function readResponseBody($sock, array $headers)
{
    $responseIsChunked = (isset($headers['transfer-encoding']) && stripos($headers['transfer-encoding'], 'chunked') !== false);
    $contentLength     = (isset($headers['content-length'])) ? $headers['content-length'] : -1;
    $isGzip            = (isset($headers['content-encoding']) && $headers['content-encoding'] == 'gzip') ? true : false;
    $close             = (isset($headers['connection']) && stripos($headers['connection'], 'close') !== false) ? true : false;

    $body = '';

    if ($contentLength >= 0) {
        $read = 0;
        do {
            $buf = fread($sock, $contentLength - $read);
            $read += strlen($buf);
            $body .= $buf;
        } while ($read < $contentLength);

    } else if ($responseIsChunked) {
        $body = readChunked($sock);
    } else if ($close) {
        while (!feof($sock)) {
            $body .= fgets($sock, 1024);
        }
    }

    if ($isGzip) {
        $body = gzinflate(substr($body, 10));
    }

    return $body;
}

function readChunked($sock)
{   
    $body = '';

    while (true) {
        $data = '';

        do {
            $data .= fread($sock, 1);
        } while (strpos($data, "\r\n") === false);

        if (strpos($data, ' ') !== false) {
            list($chunksize, $chunkext) = explode(' ', $data, 2);
        } else {
            $chunksize = $data;
            $chunkext  = '';
        }

        $chunksize = (int)base_convert($chunksize, 16, 10);

        if ($chunksize === 0) {
            fread($sock, 2); // read trailing "\r\n"
            return $body;
        } else {
            $data    = '';
            $datalen = 0;
            while ($datalen < $chunksize + 2) {
                $data .= fread($sock, $chunksize - $datalen + 2);
                $datalen = strlen($data);
            }

            $body .= substr($data, 0, -2); // -2 to remove the "\r\n" before the next chunk
        }
    } // while (true)
}

function parseHeaders($headers, &$response_code = null, &$response_message = null)
{
    $lines  = explode("\r\n", $headers);
    $return = array();

    $response = array_shift($lines);

    if (func_num_args() > 1) {
        list($proto, $code, $message) = explode(' ', $response, 3);

        $response_code    = $code;

        if (func_num_args() > 2) {
            $response_message = $message;
        }
    }

    foreach($lines as $header) {
        if (trim($header) == '') continue;
        list($name, $value) = explode(':', $header, 2);

        $return[strtolower(trim($name))] = trim($value);
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: In this case, interpreting chunked transfer encodings and compressed content-encodings is not at issue. Additionally, HTTP/1.1 specifically outlines that servers SHOULD NOT send a `Content-Length` header if a `Transfer-Encoding` header is set. The problem at hand is why the loop stops after the first 1024 bytes in the code listed and never returns *when keep-alive is the desired behavior*. I placed the bounty because I understand all the stuff in your answer, but I can't figure out how to make it work with `Connection: keep-alive` ...

Comment: I see, then more likely there is a PHP issue if its stalling, he should be able to at least read the entire response before `fread` blocks because there is no more data available.  But it should be noted that once he has read the entire response, calling `fread` again will block indefinitely (or until the socket times out), so with a keep-alive connection, you can't use `fread` in a loop like that.

Comment: @rdlowrey: If the connection is kept alive and you continue your naïve read loop, PHP will try to continue reading until the connection is closed. If `Connection: close` is set, this is OK. If `Connection: keep-alive` is set, you need to do additional processing to know when to stop reading.

Comment: You are correct about the content-length and transfer encoding though.  You can get chunked gzip data, but in that case there would be no content-length.  You'd have to dechunk into a buffer and then inflate the resulting data.

Comment: @icktoofay Aha. I reevaluated after reading your comment and it turns out I mistook the socket timing out for the loop not iterating to completion when testing against a large response. When I raised the timeout value I was able to correctly receive the full raw http message and perform the necessary parsing.

Comment: @rdlowrey I found some old (PHP) code that does everything I described above, it needs some minor cleanup to make it a good example to post but we're just about to start a BBQ so I'll have to post it later tonight but I have something that should work for you.

Comment: @drew010 Don't feel like you need to add anything, unless you just want to do it for completeness. My problem was fixed by raising the socket timeout to a reasonable level :) Thanks again.

Comment: @rdlowrey As promised, I finally added the code.  I split some of it into functions but that was about it, didn't think it necessary to make it a class at this point.  Hope it helps you out.  This will support keep-alives, and can send multiple requests on the same connection, reads chunked responses and will decompress gzip.

Comment: Is it only in php that we cannot know the end of the message for a response with keep alive request? how about in c/c++ ? can we check whether there is no data with recv() function or will recv() work same as fread in php?

Comment: @JayapalChandran It isn't just PHP, its the nature of how keep-alive connections send data.  If you call `recv` in c/c++ and it is a blocking receive, the program will just hang because it is trying to recv when there is no more data on the socket.  You could get around it by using a non-blocking recv or set a timeout but its not ideal since by reading the headers you can know when the entire response had been read and not call `recv` unnecessarily.

Comment: oh ok. i got it. let me work with non blocking as well. thank you.

Comment: ah... while i was working on this today one thing i found was if i sent a request with connection close to google it neither sends content length nor transfer encoding... in this case we just need to rely on the feof($socket_resource) to end... isn't it? cause since it is connection close the socket read function will return false when there is no data to read... but if we send a keep alive header the google sends the transfer-encidong as chunked... i just want to mention here... your suggestions please... :)

Comment: is there any thing like we can force a server to send the encoding type... cause it is not good to request for content length cause we are requesting the webserver to buffer the content which is not good for them and since we have chunked transfer it dosent matter. may be i should go thorough the http headers manual... besides if you would like to advice me then please go ahead... :)

Comment: If you use `connection: close` there is no guarantee or way to tell the remote server to use a specific encoding or send the content length.  Most http 1.1 servers will use chunked encoding but that isn't a guarantee either.  In the event the connection is close and there is no content-length or encoding, just read while !eof or in the case of C, read until recv returns 0.

Comment: @drew010: great. and i have done experimenting. it is works well. great. besides there wasnt much difference in time between connection close and keep alive... i made 15 connections using connection close and the same with keep alive and the result was just 7 or 8 seconds in difference... your suggestions please...

Comment: @JayapalChandran At this point its probably worth opening a new question and posting your code and the differences between running as close and keep-alive.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works without any problem for me:

```
<?php
$f = fsockopen("www.google.de",80);
fwrite($f,"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n");

while($s = fread($f,1024)){
    echo "got: $s";
}
echo "finished;";
?>
```

The funny thing is that **without** keep-alive this example stalls for me.
Can you add an example that can be just copy&pasted and shows your error?

Comment: The response is bad request. i assume that you have an extra space before the word connection. besides after correcting the space and after the loop displayed all data then it got suspended cause fread is trying to read no data.