# two HTTP requests in PHP using fsockopen

Tags: php, cookies, fsockopen

I have a problem which I couldn't solve almost a week. I searched everything but couldn't find an answer. 
I need to do 3 x HTTP requests to the server and then receive answers.
First is GET request to get cookie. Second is POST with cookie and the third is redirect.

```
$host = "www.xx.com";
$user_agent = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0\r\n";
$sock = fsockopen("ssl://$host", 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$sock) die("$errstr ($errno)\n");

#########################################
#   GET 
#########################################
$request .= "GET $path HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$request .= "Accept: */*\r\n";
$request .= "Host: $host\r\n";
$request .= $user_agent;
$request .= "Connection: close\r\n";
$request .= "\r\n";
fwrite($sock, $request);

$http_response = stream_get_contents($sock);
list($headers, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $http_response, 2);

// get cookie
preg_match_all('/Set-Cookie:\s*(.*)\b/', $headers, $cookie_res);
foreach($cookie_res[1] as &$val){
    $cookie .= "Cookie: ".$val."\r\n";
}
echo "<pre><p>$headers<br />cookie: $cookie</p></pre>";

$data = preg_replace('/^\s+|\n|\r|\s+$/m', '', $data);

#########################################
#   POST with cookie
#########################################
$request2 .= "POST $path"."filter/ HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$request2 .= "Host: $host\r\n";
$request2 .= $user_agent;
$request2 .= "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;\r\n";
$request2 .= "Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
$request2 .= $cookie;
$request2 .= "Referer: $path\r\n";
$request2 .= "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$request2 .= "Content-length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n";
$request2 .= "\r\n";
$request2 .= "$data\r\n";
$request2 .= "\r\n";
fwrite($sock, $request2);

$http_response2 = stream_get_contents($sock);
list($headers2, $body2) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $http_response2, 2);

echo "<pre><p>$headers2</p></pre>";
```

So I get response after the first GET request, but I don't get response after POST request.
If I close connection after first request and reopen it again before second then it works. But I want to do it in one connection. I don't understand why it doesn't work without reconnecting. 
Please help! :)

P.S. don't recommend to use CURL because I don't have it installed on this server.

Comment: you should close the first request and open a new one

Comment: But why? I think it should work in the same connection. Btw I have an error in first GET request. Actuall ythere is "Connection: keep-alive" instead of "close"

Comment: Ben, maybe I misunderstood you. You mean close connection fclose($sock) or close request? I thought that blank line "\r\n" closes request and then I can start another one on the same connection.

Comment: if not a keep-alive connection, you need to close the socket with `fclose` and initialize a new socket with `fsockopen`. For `Get` request, you send the `request headers` to server, and server will give you the `response headers` and `response body`. For `Post` request, you additionally give the `request body`.

Comment: for keep-alive connection, you may get the chunked data, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125463/if-connection-is-keep-alive-how-to-read-until-end-of-stream-php